# UIKIT scrollspy animation fix for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, uikit

When the beowser is IE,I want to remove the attribute "data-uk-scrollspy" from all of the element. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following conditional statements to attach a JS file to your HTML:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

In your **ie.js** file, you can have something like:

```
$('*').removeAttr('data-uk-scrollspy');
```

*This assumes you are using jQuery...*

Note: However, conditional statements are no longer supported for IE10+. In this case, you have to detect the browsers using Modernizr & yepnone.js to attach your script.

Comment: I am using IE 10 , and it does not work in your method. Have you any other solution,please.